# Page doesn't render extended Polymer element

Tags: polymer

I am trying to extend the Polymer core-selector but it doesn't render on the webpage.
When I place `<shadow></shadow>` inside the `template`-tags it does render.

I don't know for sure if that is the real problem. What is the purpose of the shadow-tags? I don't find information about that in the API documentation.

Here is the link to an example: http://jsbin.com/qucitiwe/3/edit?html,console

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find some information on how to extend elements in the [Extending other elements](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#extending-other-elements) section of the Polymer documentation.

The *shadow* element renders the shadow DOM of the parent element (the DOM inside the parent's *template* element) at this exact location. So without  the *shadow* element you won't see any DOM from the parent element.

In addition, a child element can wrap the parent's shadow DOM with its own content, for example:

```
<template>
  <div>Title</div>
  <shadow></shadow>
  <div>Footer</div>
</template>
```